# How can I get the Function object in the body of such function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the Function object, while the function is executing?
I am assigning properties to my function, and want to access them.  "this" doesn't help.  Something like:

```
a.b=function(){...code...};
a.b.c=100;
```

I want to access a.b.c from the code in the function, without knowing its own name.  "this" refers to a.  How can get b?

I tried binding the function to his own object, but I couldn't.

Thank you.

I'm adding this example, I have to repeat after several different "theString" and "someSpecificValues":

```
Object.defineProperty(theObject, theString, {get: function(...){...}.bind(theObject, someSpecificValues), configurable: true});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression) for this:

```js
var a = {};
a.b = function myFunc() {
  console.log(myFunc.c);
};
a.b.c = 100;
a.b();
```

It allows code inside the function to access the function itself, but does not add the identifier to the enclosing scope.

**Edit:** Here is a more elaborate example of how the name `myFunc` *only* exists within the function:

```js
var a = {};
a.b = function myFunc() {
  console.log(myFunc.c);
};

a.b.c = 100;

a.d = function myFunc() {
  console.log(myFunc.c);
};
a.d.c = 300;

a.b();               // logs 100
a.d();               // logs 300

console.log(typeof myFunc);    // logs "undefined"

// create a myFunc variable
var myFunc = function() {
  console.log("nooooooo!!!!");
};

a.b();       // STILL logs 100. the myFunc variable in this scope
             //    has no effect on the myFunc name that a.b uses

function callFunc(theFunc) {
    theFunc();
}

callFunc(a.d);       // STILL logs 300

//  ===========================

function returnNamedFunction () {
    return function myFunc() {
        console.log(myFunc.c);
    };
}

 var iGotAFunction = returnNamedFunction();
 iGotAFunction.c = 700;

 iGotAFunction();          // logs 700
```

In the case when you cannot use a named function expression, e.g. when you are using `.bind()` on it, then an IIFE will suffice most of the time:

```js
var myObj = {};

myObj.theFunc = (function () {
    var f = function (arg1, arg2) {
        console.log(this.theProp);
        console.log(arg1);
        console.log(arg2);
        console.log(f.lista);
    }.bind(myObj, "A!");
    return f;
})();

myObj.theProp = "B!";
myObj.theFunc.lista = [1, 2, 3];
myObj.theFunc("C!");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I must put emphasis  in that I don't know b name.  Actually, I'm creating a lot of methods (like b) with the same function definition, with different names assigned from variables, in the same "a" objects and in other objects like a.

Comment: @YoArgentino If you look again, I think you will see that I'm not using `b` anywhere within the function's definition. I am fairly sure that the above is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I thank you again for your quick answer.  I want to access a.b.c from the code in the function, without knowing its own name.  I can't use the function's name in my code.

Comment: @YoArgentino You are misunderstanding how named function expressions work. I explained this in my post, but the name `myFunc` _only_ exists within the function and it can't be changed. As long as you put some name between `function` and `()`, the function will always know its own name.

Comment: @YoArgentino And if you still don't believe me, please provide an illustrative example of a scenario that you want to use where you think that named function expressions would not work. I think it is very silly to use a deprecated feature when this one works just fine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your concern, I really appreciate it.  Can't paste the actual code, it's too long, but I think this will settle the scenario (I added code to my question): I am receiving an object and many strings to add properties to the object named after each string, then assigning a getter to each with some argument binded with different values in each case:     

Object.defineProperty(theObject, theString, {get: function(...){...}.bind(theObject, someSpecificValues), configurable: true});

Didn't find a way to assign a name to the binded function.

Comment: @YoArgentino I see. The function binding does pretty much rule out named functions, but I think there's probably a way to do what you want by making use of IIFEs ([something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ccwacxrd/2/)). I don't entirely understand where having the function reference itself would come into play for a `get` accessor (the fact that it's a `get` accessor makes it hard to get at the function itself), but if you could explain that bit, I can try to propose something that works.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to explain briefly.  But I'm experimenting with it, my original intention was establish if there existed a direct way to get the object Function, and I see the only existing way is deprecated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68995/discussion-between-yoargentino-and-jlrishe).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get current function.

One is "almost deprecated" usage of `arguments.callee`. In function body it always refers to this function.

```
var a = {};
a.b = function () {
  console.log(arguments.callee.c);
};
a.b.c = 100;
a.b();
```

`arguments.callee` is forbidden in strict mode. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee).

The second one is using [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression) as JLRishe [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983378/2446102).

### `arguments.callee` pros and cons

Advantages:

- it can be safely used with `bound` functions (`arguments.callee` refers to bound function)
- it can be used with functions created using `new Function`

Disadvantages:

- it can slow your program due to disabling certain optimisations
- it's considered as almost deprecated
- it can't be used in strict mode

### Named function expression pros and cons

Advantages:

- it's faster than `arguments.callee`
- it's easier to understand how it works

Disadvantages:

- it won't work as expected with bound functions (`functionName` will refer to original function, not bound one)
- it can't be used in functions created with `new Function`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I know arguments is deprecated, but for now it seems the right way to do this.  The other way in my case, as I am binding the functions, is passing an object as a fixed argument, and adding to it a property with the reference to the new binding function.  Very odd.  I was looking for an alternative, like this you gave me.

Comment: It **is** possible to use named function expressions with `new Function`. It just requires a little cleverness: http://jsfiddle.net/fmt6f98b/

Comment: There is also the issue with IE <= 8 and named functions as they leak. e.g http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html

Comment: @JLRishe Then it becames a simplest `eval` and you lose all adventages of `new Function` (eg. easy validation is user supplied code is valid JavaScript without executing it).

Comment: @Ginden I thought we were talking about self-referencing functions. What does that have to do with validating user-supplied code?

Comment: It's one of arguments why `new Function('return function namedFunction(){'+sourceCode+'};');` is a bad idea. It's just camouflaged `eval` without any advantages of `Function`. You can as well just use `eval('function me(){}')`.

Comment: @Ginden One advantage that it retains is that the code runs in the global scope rather than the local scope. [This distinction is apparently very important to some people](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263).